# ideas of algos to solve a repetitive pattern issue

Tags: algorithm

There is a list containing numbers, which is repetitive if it has **at least one** *repetitive pattern*, otherwise it is not repetitive.

A repetitive pattern is a sequence of adjoining
numbers bigger than **T** with length **N**, and it appears repeatedly for **M** times in the list, and each instance of repetitive pattern are not overlapped with each other.

For example:

```
list A: [6, 2, 4, 2, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 2, 3, 6, 2, 4]
list B: [1, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4]
T: 1
N: 3
M: 3
```

- The list A is repetitive because it has a repetitive pattern [6, 2, 4]
- The list B is not repetitive, even [1, 2, 4], [2, 2, 2] appears repeatedly for 3 times, but 1 is not bigger than 1, and there are overlapping parts between the three repeating instances of [2, 2, 2], so both of them are not a repetitive pattern.

**Question: Can this problem be transformed into a known problem with a solution? Or is there any viable solution?**

*P.S. performance issues are not considered here.*

Comment: Please be more specific why `B` is not repetetive. Clearly, 1 is not bigger than 1, but how does that contradict the definition of repetitive pattern?

Comment: @Codor Hey,  "A repetitive pattern is a sequence of numbers bigger than T", means all the numbers are greater than 1.

Comment: @jdehesa, hey, thank you for you idea, but there is a problem of your solution: in the case of list B, [2, 2, 2] will be counted 3 times, but it is not a repetitive pattern because  there are overlapping parts between the three repeating instances.

Comment: @LeylaLee You're right, I didn't read that part right.

Comment: @jdehesa Although the "violence method"(enumeration) can certainly solve the problem, but this is a performance problem (not all of the performance problems are not considered here, haha), a good solution, of course, is better to have a good performance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea I think should work in O(L * N):

```
function isRepetitive(list : List<Integer>[1..L], T : Integer,
                      N : Integer, M : Integer) -> Boolean
    // Map from pattern to (count, last index)
    patternCounts : Map<List<Integer>[1..N], Tuple<Integer, Integer>> = empty map
    for i = 1 .. (L - N + 1)
        pattern = list[i:i + N]
        if any(j <= T for j in pattern)
            continue
        end
        if pattern not in patternIndices
            patternIndices[pattern] = (1, i)
        else
            (lastCount, lastIndex) = patternIndices[pattern]
            if i >= lastIndex + N
                patternIndices[pattern] = (lastCount + 1, i)
            end
        end
        if patternIndices[pattern][0] >= M
            return true
        end
    loop
    return false
end
```

You could even do the slight optimization of fast-forwarding `i` when you find an element below the threshold in the list.

Comment: I think it is a not bad solution